# Copy SSH Public Key from Windows to Ubuntu

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop, openssh

I am trying to get my ssh public key from my windows client to ubuntu host, but I have no idea how to. I tried to find the authorized_keys file, but had zero success. ssh-copy-id command did not work from windows. I generated the public/private key pair in PuTTYgen. I am using OpenSSH on the Ubuntu host. Any ideas on what to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Any ideas on what to do?

**1. EDIT** Download [cmder](http://cmder.net/) or use your favorite console emulator. Move your public key (id_rsa.pub) and your private key (id_rsa) to `C:\Users\yourUserName\.ssh\` create the .ssh folder if needed.

**2.** On your windows host via cmder:

`cp C:\Users\yourUserName\.ssh\id_rsa.pub C:\Users\yourUserName\authorized_keys`

**3.** On your ubuntu host:

`service ssh status` Start sshd if necessary

`mkdir ~/.ssh/` (if it doesn't already exist)

**4.** On your Windows host via cmder:

`cd C:\Users\yourUserName\`

`scp authorized_keys login-id@ubuntu-Host-Ip:~/.ssh`

**5.** On your Ubuntu host:

`chmod 700 ~/.ssh`

`chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

**6.** On your Windows host via cmder:

Test if you can ssh into your ubuntu host without login/pw auth. If yes:

`rm C:\Users\yourUserName\authorized_keys`

*(you might encounter difficulties running your ssh-agent on windows, write a comment if so)*

Comment: Are you sure that PuTTYgen has generated a C:\Users\yourUserName\.ssh\id_rsa.pub?

Answer (score 4):

#### Do this on your Windows

1. Give default values without passphrase, just press enter for all

   ```
    ssh-keygen -t rsa
   ```
2. If the authorized_keys file is not there in target Linux machine else just copy the Windows ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub content to authorized_keys file in target machine

   ```
    scp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub [linux_user]@[linux_IP/linux_hostname]:~/.ssh/authorized_keys
   ```

That's it!!!

Comment: Works perfectly, but careful since this will overwrite the existing "authorized_key"-file. If you want to use multiple keys you can just create multiple files named "authorized_key2", "authorized_key3" etc.

Answer (score 4):

**ssh-copy-id** is missing from windows but it easy to create one!

- open powershell and type:

```
notepad $profile
```

- You’ll either open the existing Profile.ps1 file, or be prompted to create a new one.
  At the notepad paste the following function:

```
function ssh-copy-id([string]$sshHost)
{
    cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh "$sshHost" "mkdir -p ~/.ssh && touch ~/.ssh/authorized_keys && chmod -R go= ~/.ssh && cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
}
```

- Close the notepad and save.
- Finally open a new powershell window and the **ssh-copy-id** will works as at linux.
  Example:

```
ssh-copy-id user@host
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your ssh agent is running, just run this from Ubuntu.

```
ssh-add -L >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to send your public key from your Windows to your Linux machine is  command in your powershell:

> cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh user@host "cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"

That should be a one-stop shop for it to work to make it a passwordless entry.

Comment: This is no different from the other PowerShell answer ...